# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{p}$ can always be written in the form $\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} + An^{p} + Bn^{p-1}+Cn^{p-2} + \cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction

The following is a problem from my textbook:

> Using the telescoping method, show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{p}$ can always be written in the form $\dfrac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} + An^{p} + Bn^{p-1}+Cn^{p-2} + \cdots$

The following is the answer from the solutions manual:
[image]
[image]

Why do we have to assume that the statement is true for all natural numbers $\le p$? What if we assumed that the statement is true for natural numbers less than $p$ and greater than or equal to $2$, since the statement is $S(r):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{r}$ can always be written in the form $$\frac{n^{r+1}}{r+1} + An^{r} + Bn^{r-1}+Cn^{r-2} + \cdots$$

Comment: Isn't it just a misprint?

Comment: I think that it is a misprint

Comment: [Written in response to your previous longer comment, which has now been deleted - it seemed accurate to me, for what it's worth.] I hadn't even noticed that! I thought the problem was only that where they wrote "for all natural numbers $\leq p$", they meant "for all natural numbers $< p$". But either it's worse than that, just as you say, or my concentration is even worse than I thought! I think you're right, but I also think I'll let someone else sort it out. :)

Comment: There is a unique polynomial such that $f(0) = 0, f(x)-f(x-1)=x^p$ thus $f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^p$, it is of degree $p+1$ with leading coefficient $1/(p+1)$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I misunderstood the problem. Now it also seems to me that the induction hypothesis should not include the case $r = p$.

Comment: from complete induction I'm used to seeing that the conditions (1) $1$ is in $A$ and (2) k+1 is in $A$ if $1, \cdots , k$ are in $A$ being satisfied implies that $A$ is the set of all natural numbers n. In this solution we perform induction on p, but the variable p is not changed to k because of the way that the problem is set up. I'm thinking if p were changed to q instead, for example, then assuming 2, $\cdots$ q-1 is true and then showing that q is true shows that the statement is true for any p $\in \mathbb{N}$. At least, that's how I think that the proof is supposed to structured.